# Filter javascript multidimensional array for values that exist at every index

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have the following multidimensional array :

```js
const arrayOfValues = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'c'],
  ['c']
];
```

I would like to create a new array containing only the values that are present at every index of my original multidimensional array. So I would end up with the following array in this case :

```js
['c']
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to do so as I am not too familiar with javascript. I'm guessing I have to apply some sort of filtering (probably map over the array and apply a specific condition) but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) along with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const arr = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'c'],
  ['c']
];
let res = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc.filter(x=>curr.includes(x)));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a persistent variable that starts with the values in the first subarray. Then iterate over each other subarray, reassigning that variable to a filtered version of the subarray currently being iterated over, filtering by whether the item is contained both in the previous subarray and the current one:

```js
const arrayOfValues = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'c'],
  ['c']
];

let previous = arrayOfValues[0];
arrayOfValues.slice(1).forEach((subarr) => {
  previous = subarr.filter(
    item => previous.includes(item)
  );
});
console.log(previous);
```